# Python - Creating a range over a set of letters

Tags: python

I have a list of names and I need to write all the surnames that start with A to L to one file and the other surnames that start with M to Z to another file. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
if surname[0] in range(A, L):
    print("a to l")
elif surname[0] in range(M, Z):
    print("m to z")
```

Comment: You should add some code to your question!

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]

import string

letters = string.ascii_uppercase
group1 = letters[:12]

group2 = letters[12:]

first_group = [i[1] for i in f for b in group1 if i[1][0] == b] #contains list of surnames starting with letters in group1

second_group = [i[1] for i in f for b in group2 if i[1][0] == b] #contains list of surnames starting with letters in group2

file1 = open('other_file.txt', 'w')
file2 = open('other_file1.txt', 'w')

for a, b in zip(first_group, second_group):
    file1.write(a+"\n")
    file2.write(b+"\n")

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Greg. Using the code you've provided in your question, this is what I would change:

```
surnames = ['Jacobson', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Abrahams', 'Putin', 'Trump', 'Obama', 'Nixon']
with open('a_to_l_names.txt', 'w') as a_to_l, open('m_to_z.txt', 'w') as m_to_z:
    for surname in surnames:
        if ord(surname[0]) in range(ord('A'), ord('L') + 1):
            print("a to l")
            a_to_l.write(surname)
        else:
            print("m to z")
            m_to_z.write(surname)
```

The additional `elif` condition is redundant. Unless you expect names to start with something other than a capital letter. You have to use `ord()` to get the Unicode code for the letter to check the range.

And just because I like to provide regex solutions whenever possible, even though you're not responding to this post, here's another method you could use.

```
import re
a_to_l_pattern = r'^[a-lA-L]{1}'
with open('a_to_l_names.txt', 'w') as a_to_l, open('m_to_z.txt', 'w') as m_to_z:
    for surname in surnames:
        if re.search(a_to_l_pattern, surname):
            print("a to l")
            a_to_l.write(surname)
        else:
            print("m to z")
            m_to_z.write(surname)
```

Comment: >>> `ord('Lincoln'[0]) in range(ord('A'), ord('L'))` gives `False`

Comment: Ah, good catch. I didn't test it all that thoroughly. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're testing the initial letter of each surname, the string method `startswith` explains what your code is about.

```
import string
a_to_l = tuple (c for c in string.ascii_uppercase if c <= 'L')

surnames = ['Jacobson', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Abrahams', 'Putin']

with open('a_to_l.txt','w') as file_a_to_l, open('m_to_z.txt','w') as file_m_to_z:
    for surname in surnames:
        if surname.startswith(a_to_l):
            print(surname, file=file_a_to_l)
        else:
            print(surname, file=file_m_to_z)
```

Comment: I understand this method and it seems perfect but I don't really get the 'startswith' part.

Comment: The intent is that the code is as close as possible to the way you would say it in English. So, "if `surname` *starts with* 'A' to 'L' then ..." gets coded as  `if surname.startswith(a_to_l):` I'm afraid I can't make it much plainer.